# Visualization - Tableau

Tags: statistics, visualization, data-visualization, tableau-api

I`m new to tableau, I have the following visualization, this is the link:

[My visualization](http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/ro/NotaTotal?%3aembed=y&%3adisplay_count=no#1)

My problem is that I don't know how to add more than one dashboard as tabs in just one dashboard. In my visualization, there are three dashboards "Nota total", "Todos los cursos", and "Cursos por ciclo", the other tabs are just sheets. Therefore, How can I present my visualization with just the three dashboards which I mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you right click a tab you should have the option to "hide sheet", in tableau reader that will prevent the sheet from getting shown when the file is opened. I imagine that it works the same for tableau public.

You can read more about hiding sheets here:

http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v6.1/public/online/en-us/id10AOA000TXW.html

Answer (score 3):

When you publish your workbook, you are prompted about which worksheets to include. There is a list of the worksheets (tabs) on the right side, with checkboxes beside each one. Only check the worksheets and dashboards you wish to be visible.